# isSet() in python threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to understand the function of isSet() in python threading

[image]

it's being called on function func(1)
[image]

What does this function trigger? I've been searching and did not found any clear answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look above to see what "self._stop" is?

Comment: yah i did. but i didnt found anything similar @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Not even on the fourth line of `__init__()`?

Comment: yah i know its there, but what i want to know is the layman's usage or explanation for isSet() @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sorry. new to threading

Comment: Which part of the `Event` documentation are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python threading have some Synchronization between threads events. like java threading. You find a class `threading.Event` that is a simple synchronization object. The event represents an internal flag like java synchronization monitor lock,and threads can wait for the flag to be set or unset.

lets say server code executed like this:-

```
>>> import threading
>>> t = threading.Event()
>>> t.wait()
```

A server thread can wait for the flag to be set:

wile the client manipulates the event as follows:

```
>>> e = threading.Event()
>>> e.isSet()
False
>>> e.set()
>>> e.isSet()
True
>>> e.clear()
>>> e.isSet()
False
```

If the flag is set, the wait method doesn’t do anything. If the flag is cleared, wait will block until it becomes set again. Any number of threads may wait for the same event.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. But i didnt see any set() or clear() function. Just the getattr() call.

Comment: @ellabells :- is use Python 3.4.3

Comment: ohhh i see. im using python 2.7. @Yogendra